# how to highlight a div for a few seconds using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to be add the following to a a page:

When a div is clicked, I want to:

1. change the background color of the clicked on div for a few seconds
2. revert back to the original background color after a few seconds

I want to do this by using only jQuery available functions - i.e. not using a plugin or anything else. I am relatively new to jQuery, but I think a possible solution involves the use of changing the class of the selected div and using a timer.

I am not sure how to put it all together though. Can anyone provide a few lines that show how to do it?

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function(){
 $('div.highlightable').click(function(){
    //change background color via CSS class
    $(this).addClass('highlighted);
    //set a timer to remove the highlighted class after N seconds .... how?
 });
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One way is to go about like this using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout):

```
$(function () {
    $('div.highlightable').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('highlighted');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('div.highlightable').removeClass('highlighted');
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [jQuery UI's Highlight Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/):

```js
$(".myDiv").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".myDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
  });

});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Just make sure to include the library: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for the **Highlight** effect.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Comment: This will not work as intended because it will hide the div after the effect is done. Instead you want to do something like: `$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);` so that the element is not hidden.

Comment: not worth the jquery ui dependency if you're not already using it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) function:

```
$('div.highlightable').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //change background color via CSS class
    $this.addClass('highlighted');
    // set a timeout that will revert back class after 5 seconds:
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $this.removeClass('highlighted');
    }, 5 * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here is an answer involving the jQuery queue() function.

```
$('.menul').addClass('red').delay(1000).queue(function(next){
   $(this).removeClass('red');
   next();
});
```

From: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/inserting-a-delay-between-adding-and-removing-a-class#14737000002257187