# Highlighting a newly added item using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user adds a new comment (divCommentHtml) to a list of comments (divComments), I would like to highlight it for a few seconds and fade it away. How can you do this with jquery? This doesn't seem to work:

```
 $('#divComments').prepend($divCommentHtml).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which is this `effect` function?

Comment: @rahul http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: for 5 seconds you can text-decoration: underline and remove after that.you can use settimeout and cleartimeout functions to do the same

Comment: Also, this seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328640/how-to-highlight-a-div-for-a-few-seconds-using-jquery)

Comment: Actually, perhaps it isn't :\

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys...I'm not able to get any of it to work, but I probably should check if I have everything right on my end.

Comment: Using @Chinmayee's test, I was able to get this to work using either of my solutions. The second one is the closest to what you already had http://jsfiddle.net/4hM3j/1/

Comment: @Phil Brown, yeah the funny thing is I can also get it to work using the jsfiddle, but it's just not working on my site.  I wonder if if it's because I'm using it on <li> instead of <div>. Shouldn't make a difference right?

Comment: @Prabhu Does't make a difference - http://jsfiddle.net/4hM3j/2/

Answer (score 4):

Using `prepend`, you're running the UI effect on the `#divComments` element.

Try this (assuming `$divCommentHtml` is a jQuery object)

```
$divCommentHtml.prependTo('#divComments').effect('highlight', {}, 2000);
```

Or perhaps

```
$('#divComments').prepend($divCommentHtml)
                 .find(':first').effect('highlight', {}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have an `effect()` out of the box. **Update** Oh it's a jQuery UI thing. Carry on :)

```
$divCommentHtml.prepentTo('#divComments').effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

I changed how it works so your method is being ran on the actual `$divCommentHtml` object.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to give $divCommentHtml an ID then run the effect after it's prepended

```
$divCommentHtml = '<div id="myID">Some Contents</div>'
$('#divComments').prepend($divCommentHtml);    
$( "#myID" ).effect( 'highlight', {}, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing parenthesis around `divCommentHtml`. Check [`Live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/FbtPE/)

```
$('#divComments').prepend($(divCommentHtml)).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

Comment: That is not necessary. And they are parenthesis, not braces. I think he means the actual variable had a `$` sigil.

Comment: and divCommentHtml appears to be a variable, not a jquery object

Comment: Thanks. But check the link i've given with and without parenthesis. without parenthesis it considers $divCommentHtml as variable [which is undefined] whereas with parenthesis is return jquery object.

Comment: @Chinmayee It may be undefined in your case. I think the OP omitted the variable, but we can safely assume it holds a jQuery object.

Comment: @alex still solution that you have given seems to be not working http://jsfiddle.net/4hM3j/ please correct this if I've done something wrong.

Comment: @Chinmayee You've a typo in your code `s/prepentTo/prependTo/`

Comment: @Chinmayee Phil spotted it - you've got a typo.